# Differentiate between swipe and click navigation in tabs in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

To better understand how our users is using our app, we want to fire an event to analytics when a user swipe to the next tab, and a different event if the user clicks to navigate to the next tab.

The tabs are created with `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` from `react-navigation-tabs`.

```
const SwipeableTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Tab1,
    Tab2,
    Tab3,
  },
  { 
    swipeEnabled: true, 
  }
);
```

I've tried listening to the following event, but the payload does not contain any information about how the user navigated (swipe vs click).

`this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', payload => console.log(payload))`

Is there any way to know if the user swiped or clicked, so that I can fire the appropriate event to analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a press listener to the tab bar as described [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/1335).

The demo code looks like this:

```
const MyTabs = TabNavigator({
  ...
}, {
  tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom /* or TabBarTop */,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom' /* or 'top' */,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {
      console.log('onPress:', scene.route);
      jumpToIndex(scene.index);
    },
  }),
});
```

Now you can simply set a flag in your `tabBarOnPress` function and check for it in your `didFocus` listener.  If the flag has been set then you know it was via tab bar press, otherwise it must be a swipe.  Note that this assumes you don't manually set the tab on your own somewhere.  But if you do, you could just set the flag in that press handler as well.

[tabBarOnPress docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html#tabbaronpress)

Answer (score 2):

There is listeners on screens, you can use swipeStart, swipeEnd or tabPress callbacks to fire your events to the analytics.

```
<Tab.Screen
  name="Chat"
  component={Chat}
  listeners={({navigation, route}) => ({
    tabPress: (e) => {
      // call your analytics events
     
    },
    swipeStart: (e) => {
      // call your analytics events
      
    },
   swipeEnd: (e) => {
      // call your analytics events
      
    },
  })}
/>
```