# React Navigation Material Top Tabs Navigator Swipe event or callback method?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hi I'm using React Navigation with its Material Top Tabs Navigator component
Everything works fine except when I enable the swipe option, I can't get a callback method to do more logic.
With Material Top Tabs Navigator, users can navigate to different screens from a tabPress or swipe the focusing screen.
I need to do more logic by catching that behavior (say changing background color whenever the screen is changed)

With tabPress event (listed from its [official doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/material-top-tab-navigator/#events)), it is easy to achieve, but I can't find any event related to the swipe action. I also tried to addListener, no logging while swiping.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._test= navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
    console.log("swiped");
  });
}
```

Any ideas? tks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56251326/differentiate-between-swipe-and-click-navigation-in-tabs-in-react-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [Navigation State](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/)  to detect which tab is currently active.

Comment: tks for the idea, I can use state.index to extend a swipe event function now

Answer (score 0):

Just add an onStateChange listener on the NavigationContainer where your Tabs are instantiated. The state return on the call back includes all the info you need.

It works for both swipes and Tab press.